# Split into two lines long string in sharppdf

Tags: c#, sharppdf

I write the below code to declare a table row with sharpPDF.

```
pdfTableRow tableRow = resultTable.createRow();
tableRow[0].columnValue = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789";
tableRow[1].columnValue = "OK";
resultTable.rowStyle = new pdfTableRowStyle(predefinedFont.csCourier, 8, new pdfColor(predefinedColor.csBlack), new pdfColor(predefinedColor.csWhite));
```

With this result:
[image]

I want split the long string of "Fase" column into or more lines. 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using addParagraph to wrap the text?

```
sharpPDF.Tables.pdfTableRow row = tbl.createRow(); // tbl is a pdfTable with columns
int iLineHeight = 12; // Height of line for wrapping
row[0].addParagraph("Your long string goes here and will wrap.", iLineHeight, sharpPDF.Enumerators.predefinedAlignment.csLeft);
```

source:
http://sourceforge.net/p/sharppdf/discussion/366672/thread/bd3e5b23